# Каким образом передать данные формы с одного домена на другой?

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день. 
Есть у меня значит сайт, на котором имеется форма метода POST.
Через нее я загружаю некий контент (Название, описание, файл и др.).
 Так вот, по некоторым причинам, а именно: ограничение кол-во файлов на 1-ом хостинг аккаунте, привело меня к тому, что решил для хранения файлов использовать 2-ой аккаунт. 

Сначала делал через iframe, но потом после некоторых проблем(переход на другие страницы был в iframe) я решил не использовать такой способ.
Вопрос состоит в том, мне нужно загрузить файл, значит нужно юзать post, но простой post не робит(думал, может по принципу GET?), можно ли это как-то осуществить?

Comment: http://php.net/Curl

Comment: "простой" пост прекрасно "робит". Особенно если догадаться, что форма у тебя не "на сайте", а в браузере.

Comment: Отправляя данные на другой сервер, у меня просто дает пустые значения, когда при тесте на 1-ом сервере все работает.

Comment: Ну файлы ты GET явно не передашь :) А для всего остального только curl, создаешь файл на 1-м сервере, где обрабатывается форма, принимаешь с нее файл и курлом отправляет на 2-й сервер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправляешь форму на свой сервер, там с помощью курла отправляешь куда нужно, парсишь ответ и возвращяешь пользователю ответ

http://php.net/Curl

P.S зачем так мучаться если есть куча дешевых хостингов без такого рода ограничений?

Comment: У меня платный на безлимит место, но с ограничением 200к файлов.